# Can you configure the material-ui datepicker so you can select dates from consecutive months while still viewing the current month?

Tags: javascript, datepicker, material-ui

I'd like to select dates from the same calendar week, but not necessarily the same calendar month. Eg. when the month begins on Saturday (1st), but I want to select Friday from the month before (30th).

Here's an example of what I mean, when you're inspecting July, but want to select one of the last days of June:

[image: datepicker material-ui consecutive]

Comment: I think you have to fork from here https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/blob/master/src/DatePicker/CalendarMonth.js take a look at the getDayElements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After extensive research and examination of the code, I can conclude this format isn't supported. I considered contributing a pull request to the repository but saw this statement [from the documentation](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/blob/master/ROADMAP.md), and decided not to invest the effort:

> ⚠️ New features based on v0.18.x have low priority and will most likely not be reviewed nor merged. We want to focus on bug fixes.

Material-ui has a new version v1.0.0 coming out in the future which will have a new datepicker component, it may be useful to add this new format as a configurable option for that.